# HERE Maps: caching geocoding results

Tags: here-api

I would like to optimise quota usage when geocoding and therefore implement caching.

Please advise what is the geocoding results validity time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legally speaking the caching time is limited by this value in the response header:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400
```

In the example above this results to 24hrs.